# What's the different between Objective functions and xgboost models?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, decision-tree, xgboost

I know that `GBtree` uses a decision tree for classification and regression,
but how can we use `gblinear` for classification problem? Doesn't it gives us a continuous prediction?

I think I am confused between the parameters *"boosters"* and "*objective function*" in xgboost.

1. What can GBtree gives us compare to GBLinear ?
2. What is the difference between "*Objective Function*" to "*Booster*"
   in xgboost?

Answer (score -1):

1. `GBLinear` gives a "linear" modeling to solve your problem. Linear
   regression is a Linear model that predict a continues value as you
   mentioned. But there are other Linear models like Logistic
   Regression which predict a value between 0 to 1 (or a probability of
   a classification problem). So if you use a booster of the `GBLinear`
   type, you should use `binary:logistic` objective function. GBtree gives a decision tree modeling to your problem.
2. `Objective function` is a function you try to minimize (it doesn't
   directly relates to the model). Mostly, objective functions defines
   some kind of error. For example, in a `Linear Regression` you have a
   heuristic that looks as follows: `Hw = w0 + w1*x1 + w2*x2 + ... +
   wn*xn` (this heuristic, is actually a way to **model** your
   problem). Where the "*Objective*" also called the "*Cost*" function,
   is similar to this: `COST = (Hw - y_pred)^2`. Your objective is to
   find `w0, ..., wn` which will minimize that error thus you will get
   a "model" that is "fit" to "solve" your problem.

   GBtree / GBlinear are **models**. A way to model your problem. The model
   worth nothing without "tuning" his "weights". With the "objective"
   function, you "tune" your "weights".

Comment: GBTree/GBLinear are algorithms to minimize the loss function provided in the objective.  Usually a model is data + algorithm, so its incorrect to call GBTree or GBLinear a model. It's correct that GBLinear will work like a generalized linear model, but it will also be a boosted sequence of linear models and not a boosted sequence of trees.